# Javascript duplicate form input

Tags: javascript, forms, datepicker, duplicates

I have a form and I need two fields to be the same. I am trying to use javascript to make the second one the same as the first, after the first is set.

Here is the javascript (above my  tag)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
      function updateDate(){        
      startDate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;      
      document.getElementById("enddate").value = startDate;
 } </script>
```

and the HTML is as follows:

```
 <span class="em-events-search-dates em-date-range">
 <input type="text" id="startdate" class="em-date-input-loc em-date-start" onchange="updateDate();" />
 <input type="hidden" class="em-date-input" name="scope[0]" value="<?php if( !empty($_REQUEST['scope'][0]) ) echo $_REQUEST['scope'][0]; ?>" />
 <input type="text" id="enddate" class="em-date-input-loc em-date-end" />
 <input type="hidden" class="em-date-input" name="scope[1]" value="<?php if( !empty($_REQUEST['scope'][1]) ) echo $_REQUEST['scope'][1]; ?>" />
 </span>
```

The issue I'm having is that when you click the form field, it opens a date selector. I'm pretty sure it uses this exact plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Unfortunately, this means that you never actually click the form field after the date is selected, and you never type anything.

I tried onmouseout on the second field (the hidden one with class em-date-input) 
I tried onchange on the first element with id startdate

There are a few that work, only if you go back and click the visible field with the date selected. The problem is, a user will never do this.

I even tried putting onsubmit="updateDate();" on the submit button, hoping that when you clicked it it would change the second date before submitting the form.. No luck. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Added alerts to see what was working and what wasn't

```
 <input type="text" onchange="alert('first');" id="startdate" class="em-date-input-loc em-date-start" />
 <input type="hidden" onchange="alert('second');" class="em-date-input" name="scope[0]" value="<?php if( !empty($_REQUEST['scope'][0]) ) echo $_REQUEST['scope'][0]; ?>" />
 <input type="text" onchange="alert('third');" id="enddate" class="em-date-input-loc em-date-end" />
 <input type="hidden" onchange="alert('fourth');" class="em-date-input" name="scope[1]" value="<?php if( !empty($_REQUEST['scope'][1]) ) echo $_REQUEST['scope'][1]; ?>" />
```

When I change the date on the second box (id="enddate") it fires the third alert. No other alerts fire, even when I change the date in the first box multiple times, or by typing.

Comment: Side note, `charset="utf-8"` isn't needed here. Also, you're "pretty sure" it uses the jQuery UI datepicker? Don't you know? If so, you have all of jQuery at your fingertips.

Comment: do you want same value in both fields or you just want two fields ??

Comment: and yes I want the same value in both fields, so that when the form is submitted it only searches on one day, instead of a range of days. If the second date is empty, it searches for anything after the first date

Comment: I don't know.. It's generated with a wordpress plugin called Events Manager and I still haven't found where in their files it generates the datepicker box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question then you may want this (confused a little about your question)

```
$(function(){
    $('#startdate, #enddate').datepicker();
    $('#startdate').on('change', function(e){
        $('#enddate').val($('#startdate').val());
    });
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qZyHQ/4/) or [**This One.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qZyHQ/5/)

Comment: Works perfect in the fiddle.. doesn't work for me. http://altitudevip.com/events/ it's the second form on the page

Comment: There is an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? ` try to fix it.

Comment: Datepicker hook was changed by Events Manager plugin to em-date-range(), once I changed that it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why not use the onchange="updateDate();" method to call the function when the form input is changed?

Comment: That's not the proper way and since you are using `jQuery` you should use it in jQuery's way.

Answer (score 2):

use form before submit event:

onsubmit="return YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE()"

Just add it your submit button.

and then set the values inside that func:

```
var YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE = function(){
    //set your hidden inputs
}
```

Comment: onsubmit works, when I put it on the <form> tag. It fills the second field, but it doesn't use the information when the form is submitted. Is this because it's adding it after processing the fields?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up an `onchange` event to the `textbox`, then copy your data after it fires. It should fire once the datepicker updates the value.

Comment: That's the thing, when I add onchange="updateDate();" to the textbox with id="startdate" and change the date, it doesn't update the second box at all

Comment: Put an alert in there and see if it fires at all.

Comment: doesn't even fire.. the second date box does, but first one never does.